# Facebook login for react-native app on android

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I am facing a problem where I need to login to Facebook in my react-native Android app. I realize there is support out there for iOS apps, but what would be the react-native way to do this for Android?

Comment: did you get solution to it?

Comment: @divyum I would try [following this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/react-native/login), (disclosure: I have not tried this yet)

Comment: Thanks Nick but I have implemented it using https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk . Just follow the steps and voila!